# A question on categories of complexes

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

For complexes $A,B$ of (left) modules over a ring with unit, we let $$\text{Hom}_\text{DG}(A,B) := \bigoplus_i\text{Hom}^i(A,B),\ \text{ where } \text{Hom}^i(A,B):= \bigoplus_v \text{Hom} (A^v, B^{v+i})$$ be the complex with differential $$d: \psi \mapsto d_B \psi - (-1)^{|\psi|}\psi d_A$$ where $\psi \in \text{Hom}^{|\psi|}(A,B)$ is homogenous of degree $|\psi|$.

Let $$\text{Hom}(A,B) := \ker d \cap \text{Hom}^0_\text{DG}(A,B)$$ and $$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{H}_0}(A,B) := H^0(\text{Hom}_\text{DG}(A,B))=\text{Hom}(A,B)/ \text{im } d$$

I have to prove that complexes with morphisms being the $\text{Hom}$-spaces form an abelian categories, with the morphisms being $\text{Hom}_{\text{DG}}$-complexes form a $\text{DG}$-category, and with the morphisms being the $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{H}_0}$-spaces form a category.

I'm doing a course where category theory has been just spoken of but hasn't been discussed well, as the course is on sheaf theory. But this is the first time I'm doing category theory or homological algebra. So, I was hoping if someone could explain what exactly is going on here. I understand what is being asked of me i.e. I'm aware of definitions, but not really sure on how to even approach this problem.

Comment: It sounds to me like your best option is to learn some category theory and come back to this later. If you absolutely have to turn in a solution to this problem do it grade reasons, I'd try to explain the situation to your professor first. If nothing else avails, I'd just try to work out a sketch with as many facts as you can (eg what are kernels and cokernels in the abelian case? Why is composition in the plain category associative?), as to do every single detail could get rather long. $\mathrm{Hom}^0_{DG}$ is the zeroth group in $\mathrm{Hom}_{DG}$, that is, it's just $\mathrm{Hom}^0.$

Comment: The request to give the DG category strikes me as particularly unreasonable, and even almost circular: the fact that "DG category" is a meaningful concept depends on the fact that complexes are monoidal closed, which is the same (once proven) as saying they form a DG category.

Comment: It's mentioned that a DG Category means that the differentials of differentials of $\text{Hom}_{\text{DG}}$-complexes interact with the composition of morphisms via the Leibniz rule: $d (\phi \psi)
= (d \psi ) \phi + (− 1 )^{ |\phi|} \phi ( d \psi )$

Comment: Well, OK, then I'd just try to verify that. Notice that if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are of degree $n$ and $k$ then $\phi\psi$ must be of degree $n+k$.